# Use of args package breaks test with "ArgError: unknown or unexpected option: --colors"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, arguments, command-line-interface

I have some TS node scripts that uses the arg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/arg) package to read in and process CLI args.  The code works fine when I invoke the script via the terminal.  The tests all pass when I run jest via npm.

However, if invoke the tests via intellij IDE, I get the following stacktrace:

```
throw new ArgError(
                          
ArgError: unknown or unexpected option: --colors
    at arg (/args/node_modules/arg/index.js:132:13)
    at main (/args/main.ts:423:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/b/args/main.ts:442:18)
    at Runtime._execModule (/Users/b/args/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1429:24)
    at Runtime._loadModule (/Users/args/b/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1013:12)
    at Runtime.requireModule (/Users/args/b/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:873:12)
    at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/args/b/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1039:21)
  ...
  ....
code: 'ARG_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
```

I have cut my code down to the following and can still repro it:

TEST - just invokes main

```
import {main} from "./main";

test("just call main", async () => {
    await main(["--dry-run"]);
});
```

SRC: main is invoked which uses args to process cli args and return them.

```
import arg from "arg";

export const main = async (processArgs: string[]) => {
    const args = arg(
        {
            "--dry-run": Boolean,
        },
        {
            argv: processArgs.slice(0)
        }
    );
    console.log("determined output: " + args["--dry-run"]);
    return {
        dryRun: args["--dry-run"]
    }
};

main(process.argv).then(() => console.log("Script complete"));
```

Unsure what I have done wrong in the test set up here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the command the IDE is running? It appears it includes some args of its own. It would be better to isolate your code from the actual `process.env` for testing purposes (currently just importing main runs the whole thing).

Comment: oh yeah - @jonrsharpe I see that now - it's adding loads! I didn't think to check that, thank you. will have to stick to the jest run

Comment: The problem’s that you can’t run the tests without invoking the script for real, more than the flags it sets. It prevents you from passing any flags to Jest too, e.g. you can’t run with coverage. Separate out the entry point to make the logic testable, as I’ve done here: https://github.com/textbook/build-info

Comment: that is great thanks! I am getting coverage from the test node script, and these are one off migrations scripts so prob not worth implementing the wrapping that you have there.   But I am glad to know how to do it if I need to add it later.  Thank you.